# How to swap the new added number into the correct position in binary heap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap, min-heap

This question of my homework has passed a list where index 1 is the new node and is also the root. Then I have to check if it's children is smaller then itself and swap it with the smaller child. I've written some code but it's not working.

```
def perc_down(data):
    count = 0
    index = 1
    l, r = 2 * index, 2 * index + 1
    while index < len(data):
        if data[index] > data[l] and data[index] > data[r]:
            min_i = data.index(min(data[l], data[r]))
            data[index], data[min_i] = data[min_i], data[index]
            count += 1
            index = min_i
    return count

values = [0, 100, 7, 8, 9, 22, 45, 12, 16, 27, 36]
swaps = perc_down(values)
print('Binary heap =',values)# should be [0, 7, 9, 8, 16, 22, 45, 12, 100, 27, 36]
print('Swaps =', swaps)# should be 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `l` and `r` values inside the while loop

```
while index <= len(data) // 2:
    l, r = 2 * index, 2 * index + 1
    if r >= len(data):
        r = index
    if data[index] > data[l] or data[index] > data[r]:
        min_i = data.index(min(data[l], data[r]))
        data[index], data[min_i] = data[min_i], data[index]
        count += 1
        index = min_i
    print(data) #Added this for easy debugging. 
return count
```

And run the loop till half values only because it's binary min heap.

Output:

```
[0, 7, 100, 8, 9, 22, 45, 12, 16, 27, 36]
[0, 7, 9, 8, 100, 22, 45, 12, 16, 27, 36]
[0, 7, 9, 8, 16, 22, 45, 12, 100, 27, 36]
Binary heap = [0, 7, 9, 8, 16, 22, 45, 12, 100, 27, 36]
Swaps = 3
```

Revised the algorithm for those indices whose children do not exist.

For : `values = [0, 100, 7, 11, 9, 8, 45, 12, 16, 27, 36]` for `100` after 2 swaps comes at index 5 which does not have a right child so when it exceeds the length of list we just set it back to original index.
Heapified list : `Binary heap = [0, 7, 8, 11, 9, 36, 45, 12, 16, 27, 100]`.

Comment: But shouldn't there be an `or` instead of an `and` in the `if` condition?

Comment: Got a problem when the list is [0, 100, 7, 11, 9, 8, 45, 12, 16, 27, 36], there should be three swaps and 100 should be at the end but now I got 100 in the middle instead.@Rahul

Comment: I've changed the 'and' to 'or' now.@Sam Chats

Comment: @Victoriavv revised the algorithm for corner cases.